# Multi-Hop SSH Tunnel for LDAP

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, tunneling, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to browse an LDAP server which is hidden inside our VPN. The topology looks like this:

```
me (at home)
|
VPN gateway (at work)
|
Application Server (server1)
|
LDAP server (server2)
```

I can connect from home through to `server1` using SSH, and `server1` can connect to `server2` via LDAP (on port 389). So my question is: how can I forward that LDAP connection from `server2` back to my local PC, in order to use something like [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) to browse the LDAP structure on my home PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless server2 has a tunneling facility of its own, it can't play any part in this. Can't you connect directly to LDAP via SSH?

Comment: Dang, I was afraid of that. No, the LDAP server is hidden from direct connections. I guess I'll have to speak to a sysadmin about that.

Comment: @GarethWestern In that case you're going to need something like an inner SSH where server2 is.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. And I agree with your vote to close this question and move to a different StackExchange.